# How to make one class a delegate of another?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a card game, as part of which I need to update my controller when `touchesEnded`. I am debating whether `NSNotification` is a way to go as compared with implementing a callback via Delegates.

The question: In general, using `Objective-C`, how can one make `class A` subscribe to events happening in `class B`?

Specifically I wonder whether **how can one formally declare one class as delegate of another?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I"m not sure if you came across it but I did a quick google search pertaining to your topic and found a related SO post [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) . I hope this helps lead you in the right direction! Also, though I'm sure you've read it already, here is the link to the MSDN page about the Delegate Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx